# Error with URL Redirection in codeigniter , I am using port 8080 "Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu) Server at sandbox.dev Port 8080"

Tags: url-rewriting

I am using VirtualBox , LAMP is installed in it. 
Now am working on a PHP codeigniter project. 
Problem : URL rewriting is not working in it. 
I am using port 8080 instead of port 80 .

Rewrite Code am using:

```
`<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  # !IMPORTANT! Set your RewriteBase here and don't forget trailing and leading
  #  slashes.
  # If your page resides at
  #  http://www.example.com/mypage/test1
  # then use
  # RewriteBase /mypage/test1/
  RewriteBase /
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
  # If we don't have mod_rewrite installed, all 404's
  # can be sent to index.php, and everything works as normal.
  # Submitted by: ElliotHaughin

  ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
</IfModule>`
```

Everything works on live server which is using port 80, is there any way to fix this on local machine?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue have been resolved :

solution :

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  # !IMPORTANT! Set your RewriteBase here and don't forget trailing and leading
  #  slashes.
  # If your page resides at
  #  http://www.example.com/mypage/test1
  # then use
  # RewriteBase /mypage/test1/
  RewriteBase /
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !^80$
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /cistudbook.ae/index.php/$1 [L]

</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
  # If we don't have mod_rewrite installed, all 404's
  # can be sent to index.php, and everything works as normal.
  # Submitted by: ElliotHaughin

  ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
</IfModule>
```

Just added the folder name in which the index.php is located .

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /cistudbook.ae/index.php/$1 [L]
```

Syntax : `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /<folder_name>/index.php/$1 [L]`